# How to use Xvnc plugin from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to port an existing Jenkins job to a Jenkinsfile. For the most part this works well but I have been unable to figure out how to make use of the Xvnc plugin. In the old Jenkins job the plugin is configured as

[Xvnc plugin settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQhTB.png)

Which is required to set the DISPLAY environment variable so that Chrome can run. The error I see in the Jenkins build output is

```
[32m27 07 2018 09:21:30.798:INFO [karma]:  [39mKarma v2.0.3 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[32m27 07 2018 09:21:30.800:INFO [launcher]:  [39mLaunching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[32m27 07 2018 09:21:30.819:INFO [launcher]:  [39mStarting browser Chrome 
[31m27 07 2018 09:21:31.277:ERROR [launcher]:  [39mCannot start Chrome
```

My (truncated) Jenkinsfile looks like this

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'java8&&chrome'
  }
  stages {
    stage ("Build") {
      tools {
        jdk 'jdk 1.8'
      }
      steps {
        step ([$class: 'Xvnc', useXauthority: 'true'])
        //wrap ([$class: 'Xvnc', useXauthority: 'true'])
        //xvnc { useXauthority(true) }
        sh './gradlew clean build -PsnapshotDeps'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that I need to enclose the gradle step with the Xvnc wrapper in some way, but none of the options have tried have been any more successful than the options that I have tried here.

Comment: @mszalbach Thanks for confirming the wrap syntax. When I studied the error message I got back from that more carefully (`no known implementation of class jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper is named Xvnc`) it occurred to me that the version of the Xvnc plugin might be out of date. I checked and it seems it does need upgrading.

Comment: @mszalbach As requested I can confirm that my installation has 1.17 of the Xvnc plugin. I see that Pipeline support wasn't added to this plugin until 1.22 and as you say 1.24 is current. I have put in a request for my Admin to get this upgraded and I'll let you know once I have had a chance to re-test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrap command is followed by a block. Everything inside the block is under the effect of the wrapper (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#wrap-general-build-wrapper).

```
 stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            wrap([$class: 'Xvnc', takeScreenshot: false, useXauthority: true]) {
                sh './gradlew clean build -PsnapshotDeps'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should contain something like this:

```
 [Pipeline] wrap
 Starting xvnc
 [jobname] $ vncserver :96 -localhost -nolisten tcp
```

addition: As stated in the comments Xvnc plugin has pipeline support added since 1.22.

For karma there is also the possibility to use ChromeHeadless which would not requiere any vnc server at all. But I am not sure if this also works for gradle karma.

Comment: I tested this with a docker jenkins and get the exact same error when the Xvnc plugin is not installed. So ensure you have the newest Xnvc and pipeline plugins installed.I used Jenkins 2.121.2, Pipeline Plugin 2.5 and Xvnc plugin 1.24. Please add you plugins and version used to the question.